# Best way to replace nils from array with elements of another array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have two arrays:

```
a = [nil, 1, nil]
b = [4, 5, 6]
```

And i want to replace nil elements from first array with related elements from second array:

```
[4, 1, 6]
```

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `zip` and the `||` operator to do it:

```
result = a.zip(b).map{ |x,y| x || y }
```

Comment: Note that this will fail if `a` contains `false`s.

Comment: If you don't care about falses, `[a, b].transpose.map {|f, s| f || s}` works as well :)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to replace exactly `nil`, but not `false` elements:

```
a.map.with_index { |e, i| e.nil? ? b[i] : e }
# => [4, 1, 6]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
a.zip(b).map(&:compact).map(&:first) #=> [4, 1, 6]
```

Steps:

```
a.zip(b)
#=> [[nil, 4], [1, 5], [nil, 6]]
a.zip(b).map(&:compact)
#=> [[4], [1, 5], [6]]
a.zip(b).map(&:compact).map(&:first)
#=> [4, 1, 6]
```

By virtue of [`Array#compact`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-compact) this approach removes `nil` elements only from the zipped pairs i.e. `false` elements are not removed.

Comment: `a.zip(b).map { |e| e.compact[0] }` 2 iterations instead of 3 :)

Answer (score 3):

Another way is by using a block when [creating this new array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#class-Array-label-Creating+Arrays) like so:

```
a = [nil, 1, nil]
b = [4, 5, 6]
Array.new(a.size) { |i| a[i].nil? ? b[i] : a[i] }
#=> [4, 1, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Still another variant:

```
a.zip(b).map{|a, b| [*a, *b].first}
# => [4, 1, 6]
```

This distinguishes `nil` from `false`, as expected. But note that you cannot use this with elements that are broken by `to_a`, such as hashes.

Comment: @ndn Yes, you are right. I was thinking about it too.